# How to get realm database size in xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

How size of realm database can be obtained in xamarin? If there is nothing available directly in xamarin based library, is there any platform specific code available?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of the database from the RealmConfiguration:

```
var config = new RealmConfiguration();
var size = new FileInfo(config).Length;
```

Comment: `FileInfo(config.DatabasePath).Length`